# tableview controller, embedded tableview, or something else for this interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out what kind of iOS user interface element(s) I should be using to create this interface:

[image: ios interface]

At the bottom of this view, there is a list of items.  This list of items can be arbitrarily long.  As such, and because of the standard detail disclosure indicator and so on, it makes sense that this is a tableview.

However, the items at the top are not tableview cells.  The obvious answer then, is to simply place a tableview on the view, i.e. an embedded tableview.  But this leads to another obvious issue, which is that this entire view should be scrollable - there will be a button for "Add Item" underneath the list of items which you will need to be able to scroll to, and the interface will be crappy if the whole view doesn't scroll.

So, I could make it so the tableview is not scrollable, and is just as tall as it needs to be to include as many items as it needs to.  Then, the entire view is embedded in a scrollview, and scrolls properly.  My concern with this relates to memory management, if I do this, I don't think I'll be taking advantage of the dynamic cell creation that is inherently part of a scrollable tableview, and will instead have dozens or even hundreds of cells instantiated when the view loads.

Another alternative would be to make the entire interface a tableview, with the top portions, and the bottom button, implemented as custom tableview cells that are different from the cells that show items.  In the past, however, I've found that this is a pain-in-the-ass too, but perhaps it's a pain I must endure.

In general, I feel like I'm missing an obvious approach here, since this seems like it ought to be extremely simple to implement, but I'm currently at a loss.  Help is appreciated!

Comment: Most likely the entire thing is a table view, with different sections, some made to look like buttons, others to look like table elements etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jjv360 mentioned it correctly, this should be 1 tableview with sections and custom cells. The different look comes from nice images.

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'll accept your answer, even though the credit really ought to go to jjv360, simply because I can't accept his!  I appreciate you taking the time to respond in any case.

Answer (score 1):

It's all a tableview with a single cell type, and 4 sections.
The cell has an optional image, a label and the optional disclosure indicator. If those don't exist, the label expands to encompass the full space.
It's very easy to do, quite standard.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it.